# Small size screen and no custom application icon

Tags: android, android-screen

I have an application and I put in drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi and drawable-mdpi a custom image which should be the icon of the application.

When the app is installed on a big screen device (4.3" or 3.7"), I can see the app icon, but when I am trying to install it on a small screen phone (HTC Wildfire), I get the default android app icon (the droid).

How can I set this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as the default icon. Your project will be using whatever bitmap is in your project. When projects are created there are sample icons inserted, and it looks like one of those is still in your project.

Check your bitmaps. If necessary delete all of them except the xhdpi, and it will scale down to all phone sizes. When that works, put your other images back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ollie C. Normally, in the AndroidManifest, we can declare the app icon with: android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher", If I have ic_launcher in all the 4 folders: xhdpi, hdpi, ldpi and mdpi, which one would be taken?

Comment: The one that is appropriate for the type of screen being used. If it's a ldpi device (low res screen) the ldpi will be used, if it's a hi-res, like the Galaxy Nexus, it would be the xhpdi. You can just use an xhdpi one (Android will auto-scale it) but the quality of smaller icons may not be good.

Comment: Ok, i understood wery well. Your help resolved my problem, i deleted all those foledrs, except the xhdpi and I renamed my icon which was ic_launcher in another name and changed it in the manifest fiel

Answer (score 0):

add icon in your manifest file

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_name"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: Thank you @RajaReddy P, I have allready added it in the manifest file.